# Colour Animation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like my text to fade from white to black and the background colour to change from black to white simultaneously any ideas?

Comment: Are you using any frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can animate the colour of text by default using:

`$('#element').animate({
  color: 'red'
}, 1500);`

But background animations cannot be done by default and require a plugin (links below).

jQuery: http://www.jquery.com/
Colour plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

Enjoi ^.^

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved easily with the [jQuery color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.color.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#foo').animate({
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            color: '#000'
        }, 'slow');
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="foo" style="background-color: black;">Some Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

See it in [action here](http://jsfiddle.net/jg2hQ/).

Comment: can i do this with set timeout?

Comment: is it possible to use ur method if the div is in another function that creates some text say a paragraph and the body is just <body id=body>???

Comment: @Sam, I don't understand your question, a DIV is into the DOM, how can it be in another function?

Comment: no sorry i ment can i put the div into the script instead of body